# How to compute only part of molecular Hessian accurately (hybrid Hessian or partial Hessian calculation)?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, gaussian, geometry-optimization, orca

Hessian is required for minimisation and transition state (TS) optimisation algorithms. While the full Hessian at a certain level of theory is calculated usually for TS optimisation, usually minimisation starts from an approximate Hessian estimated from force-fields.

I found an option that is available in many popular QM packages like ORCA or Gaussian16, where only some parts of the Hessian are calculated accurately at the current level of theory (e.g., DFT) and the rest are estimates. The Gaussian16 [manual](https://gaussian.com/opt/) mentions:

> Compute some or all of the Hessian numerically: You can ask the optimization program to compute part of the second derivative matrix numerically. In this case each specified variable will be stepped in only one direction, not both up and down as would be required for an accurate determination of force constants. The resulting second-derivatives are not as good as those determined by a frequency calculation but are fine for starting an optimization. Of course, this requires that the program do an extra gradient calculation for each specified variable. This procedure is requested by a flag (D) on the variable definition lines:
>
> 1 2 D 
> 1 2 3 D
>
> This input tells the program to do three points before taking the first optimization step: the usual first point, a geometry with the bond between atoms 1 and 2 incremented slightly, and a geometry with the angle between atoms 1, 2 and 3 incremented slightly. The program will estimate all force constants (on and off diagonal) for bond(1,2) and angle(1,2,3) from the three points.

The ORCA website also mentions this option:

> Hybrid Hessians are an alternative to calculating the exact full Hessian. By selecting only a few atoms of the systems for which to calculate the Hessian one can get a much cheaper, yet often useful Hessian to aid geometry optimizations or saddle point searches.

This seems to be a very useful option for TS optimisations for large systems where obtaining the full Hessian might be expensive.

However, I haven't been able to find any reference where the exact mathematics of this procedure is shown (in terms of the matrix). As I understand, in the Cartesian Hessian eigenvectors, the effects of different bond stretch, and angle bends are mixed together. For internal coordinates like redundant or delocalised, I have no idea how they work. The gradients are always estimated in Cartesian coordinate system however so I imagine a coordinate transform is needed.

How is the hybrid/partial Hessian calculation is done (i.e. the maths procedure to construct the Hessian matrix)?